# Cannot access individual JSON values / jQuery-Ajax

Tags: jquery

I am working on a webpage that utilizes an API from some website which generates random quotes. I am attempting to use AJAX/jQuery to access the JSON that is delivered by the API. I have tried a million different things but for the life of me I cannot access the values of the JSON by their ID. I can access the whole JSON. But I can't seem to access the individual values.

This code...

```
function init() {
var $data = $('#data');

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=famous',
  type: 'GET',
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
     $.each(JSON.parse(data),function(i, quote) {
       $data.append('<p class="text-center"> '+quote+ '</p>');
     });
   },
   error: function(err) { alert(err); },
   beforeSend: function(xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization"");
    }
  });
}
window.onload = init;
```

This is giving back all of the values, and they are in the correct format. But it gives back all of them. I don't want the last one, and I would like to be able to access each value by ID individually.

```
{
  "quote": "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how    improbable, must be the truth.",
  "author": "Sherlock Holmes",
  "category": "Famous",  
}
```

Above is what the JSON looks like. I only want access to the first two values. When ever I try to access them with something like...

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=famous',
  type: 'GET',
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    document.write('<p>' + data.quote + '</p>');
  },
  error: function(err) { alert(err); },
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "");
  }
});
```

I've tried a million different things but no matter what I do I cannot get access to the values of the JSON by their ID. This is my absolute first time messing with using a web API so I must be missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's an extra comma in your Question's JSON and also an extra quote in `xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization"");` 
Try https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and http://www.jslint.com/ to validate your code.

Comment: You can not use `document.write` after page has loaded....it will wipe everything else in the whole page out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
...
success: function(data) {
   var items = JSON.parse(data);
   $data.append('<p class="text-center"> '+ items[0].quote + '</p>');
},
...
```

Comment: JSON.parse is not needed for `dataType:'json'`

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. All I had to do that was a little different from your suggestion was drop the [0] in the items.quote. Now I am able to access each value on it's own and do with it as a please.... within my abilities of course :) Again, thank you very much. You really got me unstuck here!